# Can TypeScript infer generics from function return values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble coming up with the types for a library function that I'm trying to write. The types seem to be inferred correctly when my function takes a raw object, but breaks when it's updated to take a function returning that same object.

The function accepts an options object that has the following structure:

```
interface Options<Key, Result> {
  key: Key;
  format(key: Key): Result;
}
```

That type is used to create a `buildStore` function (right now it's just an identity function to illustrate the types.)

```
function buildStore<Key, Result>(options: Options<Key, Result>) {
  return options;
}

const store = buildStore({
  key: {id: 32},
  format(key) {
    // key correctly inferrred as {id: number}
    return key.id.toString();
  }
});

// Result still correctly inferred as string
store.format({id: 10})
```

This breaks when I update the types to pass a builder function instead of the options object directly:

```
function buildStore<Key, Result>(options: (...args: any[]) => Options<Key, Result>) {
  return options();
}

const store = buildStore(() => {
  return {
    key: {id: 32},
    format(key) {
      // key is of type "unknown"
      return key.id.toString();
    }
  }
});

// Property 'fn' does not exist on type '(...args: any[]) => Options<unknown, any>'.
store.format({id: 10})
```

I would expect for the types to still be correctly inferred when returning the object from a function, but it doesn't seem like that's the case. Is this a limitation of TypeScript, or am I not handling the generics correctly?

Comment: You forgot to call `options` in the second codeblock.

Comment: However, [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nll4RN) seems like a bug to me...

Comment: Ah you're right, nice catch, and thanks for the example. That does seem weird.

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with some sort of context issue and it's a design limitation of TS; perhaps since block bodies for arrow functions can bring other variables into scope the compiler delays some analysis and it fails.  But I couldn't find an existing TS issue that's definitely relevant so I can't answer authoritatively enough for Stack Overflow.  Someone might want to file one in GitHub and then answer here when it gets triaged.

Comment: Ah, so it was considered a bug when it was reported previously at [ms/TS#50687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50687) and has been fixed for the next release of TS, as you can see [in this nightly-build playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nll6BN).  I'm happy to write this in an answer but I'll defer to OP if they want to write it themselves if they filed [ms/TS#53954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53954)... let me know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't mind if you write up the answer, I appreciate the follow-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in TypeScript, originally reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#50687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50687) (and subsequently re-reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#53954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53954) specifically to answer this question).  It has  to do with marking functions as *context-sensitive* because the compiler thinks its type might depend on surrounding code... which causes inference to be delayed, and sometimes fail entirely, if the compiler detects a circular dependency.

Such circular dependencies can occur quite easily when the compiler needs to infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments at the same time as it needs to [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) infer unannotated function parameters.  The general problem of inference failing in situations like that can't be entirely fixed in TypeScript without a complete reworking of the inference algorithm to implement *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), and that's unlikely to ever happen because [according to the language's chief architect](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065) in [microsoft/TypeScript#17520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065), the current algorithm " it has the distinct advantage of being able to make partial inferences in incomplete code which is hugely beneficial to statement completion in IDEs."  So the *general* situation is essentially a design limitation of TypeScript.

But *specific* instances of the issue can be addressed, and there has been steady improvement.  In particular the bug you ran into has been fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#50903](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50903) by changing how function block bodies are marked for context-sensitivity.  It is slated to be released with TypeScript 5.1, and until that's released you can use [the nightly `typescript@next` build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/next) if needed.

[Playground link to code using version `typescript@5.1.0-dev.20230422`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.0-dev.20230422#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8A0hAJ4A0yAShHgK4A2YAfMgN4BQyyA1mQFzISpANxdkMbFAC2cMAAo+pQcICUgmvSZiAvhw4w6IBFlzIARnWAMAJgGUwUiMTKVNjFvOyYc+QfIA6ILgoAHM8QTgQUgBtAF1VZABeVgxTfBcKaloPZkTObigIMDooEGRvdLx5VV19BFw8MGQmp2SLK1sHJ3ka5NYC5CKSsvZxbiVBNmAbQQBmACYdcnGJKVkFJXzV7gB6Xd4yZGA8CphkMFJ0FAAiIx4QbAB3EBudoeLS8qUAmYDHBxQUChGpibjcPQQjg6Wr6fbIAAKUG80EuyAA5DAQOjkDZsLRkI9mhAAB4nZpmS7XDGBYJhCLIKKxBL9NA+RoEe6PF6UJnMdEBDitIoBSQyOTyaazZAARgADDCOEA)